# How do I get around the Esben bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I return Esbern's voice?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36621/how-do-i-return-esberns-voice)

In the main quest I need to find Esben in the *A Cornered Rat* quest.  I've talked to him and according to the journal he's agreed to let me in.

However, the door does not open and nothing happens.  If I use the console and use `tcl` to get round the door Esben is mute and does not respond.  Obviously some trigger has not been set; how do I get around this?

Comment: When i talk to him, he is muted, and subs goes very fast, i can't even read what he says. Then, i hear doors opening, but they are closed. I see he is moving in that room, but i can't get access to him. Dunno what's wrong

Answer (score 2):

Not opening the door isn't the bug; not hearing him is.

He takes a rather long time (in game terms, anyway; something like 60 seconds) to open the door.  While he's doing this, you're supposed to hear him muttering and fiddling with the locks.  However, [there's a bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36621/how-do-i-return-esberns-voice) which prevents you from hearing him, which makes it appear that he simply isn't opening the door at all.

Either try the workaround shown in that question or just park yourself in front of his door for a minute after talking to him while you grab a drink or a snack.

Answer (score 0):

Esben becomes a follower after you talk to him, so if you already have a follower you need to park him or her outside the Ratway Warrens area. Then go in again and the door will be open.

Comment: I had Lydia with me throughout this quest.  Once I reached Esbern, they both behaved like followers until I dropped him off.